# Staging test errors: Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle

Tags: solidity, javascript, testing, error, unittesting

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config");

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("Raffle Staging Tests", function () {
      let raffle, raffleEntranceFee, deployer;

      beforeEach(async function () {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer);
        raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee();
      });

      describe("fulfillRandomWords", function () {
        it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async function () {
          // enter the raffle
          console.log("Setting up test...");
          const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp();
          const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

          console.log("Setting up Listener...");
          await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            // setup listener before we enter the raffle
            // Just in case the blockchain moves REALLY fast
            raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
              console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!");
              try {
                // add our asserts here
                const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner();
                const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState();
                const winnerEndingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance();
                const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp();

                await expect(raffle.getPlayer(0)).to.be.reverted;
                assert.equal(recentWinner.toString(), accounts[0].address);
                assert.equal(raffleState, 0);
                assert.equal(
                  winnerEndingBalance.toString(),
                  winnerStartingBalance.add(raffleEntranceFee).toString()
                );
                assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp);
                resolve();
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
              }
            });
            // Then entering the raffle
            console.log("Entering Raffle...");
            const tx = await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee });
            await tx.wait(1);
            console.log("Ok, time to wait...");
            const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance();

            // and this code WONT complete until our listener has finished listening!
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

I am facing this error here:
**1) Raffle Staging Tests
"before each" hook for "works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner":
Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle
at Object.getContract (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:447:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at Context. (test/staging/Raffle.staging.test.js:12:18)**

can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this code block is valid?

```
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer);
```

I would say it is not correct, but I also assume there are may be multiple ways to deploy a contract in tests.

Here is how I did a similar case:

```
import { time, loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";
import "./SwapChainV2";
import "./SwapValue";

describe.only("SwapChain V2 test", async function () {

    async function deploy() {
        const factoryUtils = await ethers.getContractFactory("Utils");
        const contractUtils = await factoryUtils.deploy();

        const factorySwapValue = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapValue");
        const contractValue = await factorySwapValue.deploy();

        const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapChainV2");
        const contractSwapChain = await factory.deploy(
            contractUtils.address, 
            contractValue.address
        );

        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

        return { contractSwapChain, contractValue, contractUtils }
    }

    it("On register new user, get users call returns relevant count", async function() {
        const { contractSwapChain } = await loadFixture(deploy);
        // the rest of the test case
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, this did the job!